# Clear multiple forms on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, reset

I have five small forms on one page. When the page is loaded via the top menu all fields are blank or default. When the page is loaded via the browser back button the fields retain their previous selection or entry data.
What I want to do is have the forms clear down when the page is loaded via the browser back button so no matter how the page is loaded the fields are always blank or default.
This is the page - http://www.heat-sink.co.uk/index.php?page=extruded.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset all forms:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('form').each(function() { this.reset() });
});
```

Comment: I never thought it would be this straightforward and use so little code. Thanks boszio.

Answer (score 4):

In your document ready event reset form like below

```
 $(function(){

 $("form").reset();

 });
```

I decided to test the above and it didn't work because JQuery has no reset() method but javaScript does. So to use the above, convert the jQuery element to a JavaScript object like

```
$("form")[0].reset();
```

But the code below works so you can use it.

```
    $(function(){

        $('form').trigger("reset");

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide ID to your forms and in document ready event put below code:

```
document.getElementById("kk").reset();
```

Note: here `"kk"` is id of form. If you have 5 forms as you mentioned, you have to assign them with different ids and each form you have to reset separately using above code.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if we have two forms. With the help of the following two functions written in JavaScript, we can reset and submit for those two forms.
(Form 1 and Form 2 are two form IDs.)

```html
<script>            
  submitForms = function(){
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    document.getElementById("form2").submit();
    }
  resetForms = function(){
    document.getElementById("form1").reset();
    document.getElementById("form2").reset();
    }

</script>

<input   type="submit" value="send " onclick="submitForms()" >
<input   type="reset" value="cancel "  onclick="resetForms() ">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).